# Send access token in cookie spring boot Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth

I am using spring security OAuth for authentication and authorization.Now access token and refresh token are being sent in response body.How to send them back in cookie after getting tokens from UserPrincipal but not in response body.

Which configuration method I have to override to do this response?

Comment: You can handle the same in doFilter method of your Filter implantation.

Comment: Any code for setting cookie in Filter Implementation?That would be of great help

Comment: After retrieving token, user have to set it as bearer token and send